# Unable to create user when installing solr 6.2.0 on centos 7

Tags: bash, apache, solr, centos, centos7

`cd /tmp`

`wget http://www-us.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/6.2.0/solr-6.2.0.tgz`

`tar xzf solr-6.2.0.tgz solr-6.2.0/bin/install_solr_service.sh --strip-components=2`

`[root@ns52132 tmp]# sudo ./install_solr_service.sh solr-6.2.0.tgz`

```
id: solr: no such user
Creating new user: solr
adduser: group '--disabled-password' does not exist

Extracting solr-6.2.0.tgz to /opt


Installing symlink /opt/solr -> /opt/solr-6.2.0 ...


Installing /etc/init.d/solr script ...


/etc/default/solr.in.sh already exist. Skipping install ...


/var/solr/data/solr.xml already exists. Skipping install ...


/var/solr/log4j.properties already exists. Skipping install ...

chown: invalid spec: ‘solr:’
./install_solr_service.sh: line 322: update-rc.d: command not found
id: solr: no such user
User solr not found! Please create the solr user before running this script.
id: solr: no such user
User solr not found! Please create the solr user before running this script.
Service solr installed.
```

The same steps are mentioned in many sites, the one I am following is https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-and-configure-solr-on-ubuntu-1604/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit `install_solr_service.sh`, find the following line

`adduser --system --shell /bin/bash --group --disabled-password --home "$SOLR_VAR_DIR" "$SOLR_USER"`

and replace with

`adduser --system --shell /bin/bash --home "$SOLR_VAR_DIR" "$SOLR_USER"`

According to the [man page for `adduser`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/adduser) :

`The default is to disable the password.` Hence, removal of `--disabled-password` should not have any impact after changing the command.

Not sure about the impact of removing `--group` but I believe that's to select the default user-group, which is now the default behavior.